# View controller-based status bar appearance set to YES breaks app layout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, info.plist

Because I wanted to change the color of the status bar in my application, i needed to set the '*View controller-based status bar appearance*' option in Info.plist on YES. However, after I cleaned and rebuilded the project, my application suddenly looks like this....?

[image]

Any way how i can fix this? My app usually just looks like this

[image]